# How to route a specific IP through a specific NIC (PC have 2x Interfaces)

Tags: networking, routing, gateway

I have a PC with two Interfaces.

One is always left as DHCP (and for Internet access via a LAN cable at work).
The second is with a fixed IP and Subnet Mask, to communicate with another Linux machine via a Switch.
The PC has an IP set to [10.10.10.20]
The Linux machine has the IP [10.10.10.9]

[image: in the photo you can see the result of ipconfig]

```
> Ethernet adapter Linux:
> 
>    Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :    
>    IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 10.10.10.20
>    Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.224.0
>    Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . :
> 
> Ethernet adapter Internet:
> 
>    Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : united4all.nl
>    IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 10.1.1.111
>    Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.252.0
>    Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 10.1.0.1
```

The problem is, if I try to use the IP address of the Linux machine, (in an Internet browser), it seems like the browser is looking for it on the internet. And it doesn't go directly to the Linux machine. And of course it can't find anything.

If I disable the DHCP interface, then it works.
I notice that my "Linux" network interface doesn't have any Default Gateway.
it only exist in the 2nd interface (DHCP).

Do I need to set it up?

Route print:
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/UK1Pb.jpg]

Network Settings:
[image: How the Network device are set on Windows]

Comment: What is is on the machine? Windows? What does route print show?

Comment: yes, the machine is Windows 10 Pro.

Comment: Your network config seems to be ok. Can you ping the Linux machine?